# RETORNAR IMAGEN DE BASE DE DATOS Y MOSTRAR EN NAVEGADOR

Tags: php, mysql, web, backend

quisiera que me ayudaran con una pequeña duda que tengo, es posible guardar imágenes en bases de datos y retornarlas al navegador pero que funcione como si se estuviera leyendo solo la imagen? Espero me hayan entendido, igual aquí les dejo un ejemplo: https://falabella.scene7.com/is/image/FalabellaPE/181031-hero-category-moda-1?scl=1&qlt=100&cache=off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si es posible, tienes dos opciones:

1. Guardas el camino de la imagen en la base de datos y la imagen en una carpeta adonde vas hacer uploads de las imagenes, y cuando quieres mostrar la imagens en el navegador, simplemente buscas el camino en la base de datos eslache, la imagen y cu formato, y lo muestras en en html ej: C:/xampp/htdocs/tuproyecto/uploads/imagen.jpg
2. guardas la imagen en formato string base64, alli tendras la misma imagen codificada en la base de datos, y a la hora de mostrar, solo tienes que descodificarla.

Espero tener ayudarlos, para mejor explicaciones, exponga el codigo....